# Can someone explain this line of code?

Tags: c++, vector, int

```
void Player::removeWeapon(int location)
{
    if (location<(int)weaponInCharacter.size()) {
        weaponInCharacter.erase(weaponInCharacter.begin() + location);
    }
}
```

I'm unsure of the following line:

```
if (location<(int)weaponInCharacter.size()) {
```

I can see that its comparing the int location to the location in the vector weaponInCharacter but what is it doing between the int and the vector in this part of the code :(int)weaponInCharacter.size())

Comment: It's a condition: if location is less than vector size casted to integer.

Comment: size() returns a size_t value. Casting it into int avoid a compiler warning.

Comment: Wouldnt size() return an int though?

Comment: @Jepessen: and also potentially masks integer overflow issues...

Comment: @user2294616: No, `size()` in standard containers returns `size_t`, which is typically andunsigned integer type. If you compare a `size_t` with an `int` you will often get a compile warning about comparing a signed type with an unsigned type.

Comment: @vanza you're right, I was only explaining the casting.

Comment: If the size of `weaponInCharacter` exceeds `INT_MAX`, you probably have other problems in the code that dwarf the overflow problem. Or, at least, that is one heck of a fearsome weapon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(int)` is simply the old C-style cast of the value to `int`.

This is a very common idiom. The return value of `size` is `size_t`, which is unsigned. When you try to compare this to a signed `int`, many compilers will give a warning. To eliminate the warning you can simply cast the `size_t` to an `int` and everything will be OK, as long as you know that the value returned by `size` will fit in an `int`. It would be vanishingly rare for the return value not to fit in an `int`.

Comment: I'd recommend fixing the API to take a `size_t` instead, instead of saying the cast is OK. Then the code will be correct. Warnings exist for a reason.

Comment: @vanza you'd just be pushing the problem another level up in the code; eventually you're probably going to reach a point where `int` really is the proper type to use.

Comment: Not sure I can agree with that - `size_t` is the correct type to use here, always. But anyway that's beyond the question's scope (sort of).

Comment: @vanza pushing unsigned types farther into the program than is necessary is a bad solution, because unsigned types are inherently dangerous due to their "cliff" behavior around zero. If you're worried about overflow, you can add a wrapper interface which gets the size of the object as an `int`, and checks that the value fits (and raises an exception or whatever). If the size of `weaponInCharacter` is anywhere near `INT_MAX`, that anyway probably points to a deeper problem, like corruption; containing the value properly in another `size_t` is not the fix.

Comment: @Kaz Still not convinced. It's perfectly valid for something to hold more than INT_MAX. By using an int, you're just choosing to handle the overflow over the "cliff" you talk about (something I've never run into in real programs, unlike the overflow). Large files, mapped memory, lots of things can overflow an int easily.

Comment: @vanza all of the things you mentioned that would overflow an `int` do not apply to the standard containers. The only circumstance I can think of that would is if you're on a 64-bit machine but your `int` type is 32 bits, and even then you'd need to populate it with over 2^31 elements. If that's a possibility you're probably aware of it and taking extra precautions anyway.

Comment: @vanza It's also perfectly valid for something to be greater than SIZE_MAX. What's your point? That the size of the container `weaponInCharacter` couldn't be larger than this? Why not? What if the size is at `SIZE_MAX` already and the program appends more data?  What if it's not expected or reasonable for `weaponInCharacter.size()` to be even as high as 100? Then this is all moot.

Comment: @MarkRansom I guess I've been developing for too long in 64-bit environments, where it's very common to get int and size_t mixed up and cause bugs, and tend to use size_t wherever a size is needed. Kaz: You can't have more than SIZE_MAX in a container, but you can have more than INT_MAX in one.